# How to get youtube channel name from youtube v3 api in android

Tags: android, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, android-youtube-api

is there any way we can get the channel name of our logged-in google account in android using [youtube's v3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3)?

I didn't found any documentation related to the channel name.
I don't want videos and playlists I need a channel name

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can easily get `channelTitle` variable in `Snippet` object of youTube API.

Comment: I am getting channel name but I have all channel names which is created in the same account, I have added multiple channels in my google account how can I access them?